# Adding a single field into group django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'd like to know how to add a single field to a group of fields in a fieldset in DjangoAdmin. I've got this:

```
class SecretarioAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model=Secretario

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = list(super(UserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj))
        # update the `fieldsets` with your specific fields
        fieldsets.append(('Administrar', {'fields': ('administrar')}))
        return fieldsets
```

That's my model:

```
class Secretario(Usuario):
    administrar = models.OneToOneField(CentroEducativo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Unknown field(s) (i, a, r, s, m, d, t, n) specified for Secretario. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class SecretarioAdmin.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding comma(`,`) after `'administrar'` should solve your error.
As error considers `administrar` as tuple of characters rather than a tuple with single element.

Correct code should look like this :

```
class SecretarioAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model=Secretario

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = list(super(UserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj))
        # update the `fieldsets` with your specific fields
        fieldsets.append(('Administrar', {'fields': ('administrar', )}))
        return fieldsets
```

**Reasoning :**

In python, single string in `()` is string and not tuple with single element.

> t = ('sample')
>
> type(t)
>
> > str
>
> t = ('sample',)
>
> type(t)
>
> > tuple

Comment: Read Django's offical documentation on `fieldsets` :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets